# SQLite database query assigned to a ViewModel variable

Tags: c#, sqlite, syntax

Can anyone tell me why I am getting "The name 'Vehicle' does not exist in the current context" from this code? It's in the last line where I am trying to concatenate a string for a page header.  Please realize that I am new at c#, new at Windows Store Apps, new at SQLite, and maybe more.  I can't understand if I just queried the db and assigned the values to construct 'Vehicle' why does it not recognize it in the very next statement?

```
public MainPrintPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MaintenancesViewModel = new maintenancesViewModel();
        Maintenances = MaintenancesViewModel.GetMaintenances(App.CurrentVehicleId);
        MaintenancesViewSource2.Source = Maintenances;

        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
        {
            var query = db.Table<vehicles>().Where(
                    p1 => p1.VehID == App.CurrentVehicleId).SingleOrDefault();


                var Vehicle = new vehicleViewModel();

                    Vehicle.VehID = query.VehID;
                    Vehicle.VehYear = query.VehYear;
                    Vehicle.VehMake = query.VehMake;
                    Vehicle.VehModel = query.VehModel;

        }

        string PageTitle = string.Format("{0} Maintenance Records", Vehicle.VehYear + " " + Vehicle.VehMake + " " + Vehicle.VehModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the `using` scope and assign within.  You must assign it a value such a null or new, else you'll get a "not initialized" error.

```
vehicleViewModel Vehicle = null;
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
{
  ...

  Vehicle = new vehicleViewModel();
  ...
}
```

Side note, your naming conventions are opposite of what the vast majority of C# programmers would use.  Instead first letter of class names should be upper case, and local variables should be lower case, like so:

```
VehicleViewModel vehicle = null;
vehicle = new VehicleViewModel();
```

Comment: Thanks very much, to both of y'all (AaronLS and Alex).  I'm just an old guy stumbling along, but with the great help I often get here, I'm squeaking by.  I'll make a note of that variable capitalization convention.  I have such a jumble of upper and lower case now, I doubt I can sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

`Vehicle` is declared in your `using` statement, it's out of scope in the final line. Try declaring `Vehicle` before the `using` statement.